# Apache : socache_shmcb:error AH00820: shared memory segment too small

Tags: apache-2.4, rhel7

For the context : Apache HTTPD 2.4.6-90.el7 on RHEL 7.4

- I had a `AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]` warning in the logs, so I added to the configuration :

```
<IfModule socache_shmcb_module>
    SSLSessionCache shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
</IfModule>
```

- I checked the `socache_shmcb_module` module is loaded :

```
$ httpd -M | grep shmcb
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
```

- I checked the syntax was fine :

```
$httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

- then did a graceful restart :

```
httpd -k graceful
```

- afterwards, I saw no more `AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]` warning in the logs. Hours later, the whole HTTPD server was not functional anymore and the logs reported :

```
[socache_shmcb:error] AH00820: shared memory segment too small
```

The [Apache documentation itself](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache) gives no details about the size of this cache, the value I applied is actually the one shown in examples.

How may I determine the acceptable size of this cache ? Do you have any details regarding this *AH00820* error ?

Answer (score 0):

The output of mod_status includes a section on session cache status and usage. Here's what it looks like on our host:

```
SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 512000 bytes, current entries: 0
subcaches: 32, indexes per subcache: 88
index usage: 0%, cache usage: 0%
total entries stored since starting: 0
total entries replaced since starting: 0
total entries expired since starting: 0
total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 0
total retrieves since starting: 0 hit, 8 miss
total removes since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
```

You could monitor that, and/or double the cache size until the problems go away.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do you get the SSL/TLS status information with `mod_status` ? I can't manage to get these, even with `ExtendedStatus on`. Is this feature available in Apache 2.4 as suggested in this question : https://serverfault.com/questions/414411/session-cache-is-not-configured-why ?

Comment: No special configuration of mod_status. Our host is RHEL7, but note that we're running httpd 2.4.34 from RHSCL, not the stock Apache which is 2.4.6. That may make a difference since many improvements were introduced in 2.4.7.

Comment: I've been able to setup `mod_status` on Apache 2.4.6-90.el7 and let it report about SSL/TLS cache status. Please note that the "Machine readable status" described in the documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) does not display the "SSL/TLS Session Cache Status" block, only the web status page has it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question : my mistake was I added to the Apache configuration :

```
<IfModule socache_shmcb_module>
    SSLSessionCache shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
</IfModule>
```

The crash and `AH00820` error did not occur again after I changed that to :

```
<IfModule socache_shmcb_module>
    SSLSessionCache shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```

The [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache) mentions that `SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300` is the default value, which is why I initially omitted it. Looks like this directive is mandatory, even to repeat the default value.

Back to my initial questions :

**1. How may I determine the acceptable size of this cache ?**

Once Apache is configured with both `SSLSessionCache` and `SSLSessionCacheTimeout` directives, it is stable again and `mod_status` (described in the answer + comments above) outputs the percentage of cache used. It's pretty low in my case, so the configured value `512000` looks fine.

**2. Do you have any details regarding this AH00820 error ?**

Not much about this error, actually. I just can tell it disappeared when I used both directives.